# SQL 2 date ranges overlapping day count

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a simple web app where users log in and assign ONE date range of when they are free to OFFER some days off, and ONE date range of when they WANT some days off. This takes the form of a Request. User A offers "Jan 01-Jan31" and wants "May 01-May31".

Now user B puts in a request where they OFFER May and also WANT January. In this example, the the requests match.

```
 Requests Table
 --------------
 "User A", "20170101", "20170131", "20170501", "20170531"
 "User B", "20170501", "20170531", "20170101", "20170131"
```

However, I need it a little bit more complicated than that. Users may not offer or want whole months, but a specific date range, such as :

User A offers Jan01-Jan31 but wants May20-May27

User B offers May15-May31 but wants Jan01-Jan05

In that example, they both match too, however **I need to calculate the number of days that each request overlaps another** and the request will only match if that overlap number >= X days (say an application set constant of 4 days).

So, each request is unioned with each other again, (to compare every request against every other request) and there needs to be the overlap day count to check for a match.

I found this formula which offers if there *is* an overlap, but I cant seem to return the day count too:

```
 where not (t1.startdate > t2.endate or t1.enddate < t2.startdate)
```

See SqlFiddle here: [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d2576/4)

```
-- DateGivingFrom, DateGivingTo
-- DateWantFrom, DateWantTo
Create table t (Id int, uid varchar(6), 
                dgf date, dgt date,
                Dwf date, dwt date);
   Insert into t values (1,"Human1","20170101","20170131","20170501","20170507");
   Insert into t values (2,"Human2","20170501","20170531","20170120","20170125");

Select *, (select count(*) from t
           where not (v.dgf > t.dwt or v.dgt < t.dwf) )
                  as DatesOverlap,
           ("?") as OverlapDayCount
from t as v ;
```

NOTE

There will be hundreds of users each making a few requests, and also I wont do this calculation each time a user submits a request, as it may be quite intensive. Instead I will have a service which runs a "checker" to do this functionality (as it will then set notifications, send emails, etc, based on results)

This will be **php** based run in **mysql**. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea is a self-join.  I'm not sure what you really want to calculate.  The following calculates the overlap of the two periods:  "g" to "w" and then "w" to "g".

```
select t1.*, t2.*,
       datediff(least(t1.dgt, t2.dwt) greatest(t1.dgf, t2.dwf)) as gw_overlap,
       datediff(least(t2.dgt, t1.dwt) greatest(t2.dgf, t1.dwf)) as wg_overlap;
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.dgf <= t2.dwt and t1.dgt >= t2.dwf and -- t1 "g" overlaps t2 "w"
        t2.dgf <= t1.dwt and t2.dgt >= t1.dwf and
        t1.uid <> t2.uid;
```

Comment: I'm trying to calculate when a user's request "matches" with another user's request. A "match" is considered when User A is offering some days that User B wants AND User B is offering some days that User A wants. Both those situations need to have at least 4 days (application constant). I thought this would best be semantically shown by overlapping date ranges

Comment: I'm just playing with this in SqlFiddle. A couple of typos (syntax errors), but so far seems to be working beautifully, thanks. I will mark as accepted shortly if my testing doesnt flag anything up

Comment: Accepted. I can't seem to edit your answer though. I tweaked it a little to match my requirements. `<` and `>` conditions to `<=` and `>=`, also `d1.dwf` becomes `t1.dwf`. Also I've changed the diffs to `datedif(...)+1` to account for sameday = an overlap. Also added a `having` clause for when `gw_overlap >= 4` and `wg_overlap >= 4`. Many thanks!